# Understanding backoffLimit in Kubernetes Job

Tags: kubernetes

I’ve created a `Cronjob` in kubernetes with schedule(`8 * * * *`), with job’s `backoffLimit` defaulting to 6 and pod’s `RestartPolicy` to `Never`, the pods are deliberately configured to FAIL. As I understand, (for podSpec with `restartPolicy : Never`) Job controller will try to create `backoffLimit` number of pods and then it marks the job as `Failed`, so, I expected that there would be 6 pods in `Error` state.

This is the actual Job’s status:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: 2019-02-20T05:11:58Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-02-20T05:11:58Z
    message: Job has reached the specified backoff limit
    reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
    status: "True"
    type: Failed
  failed: 5
```

Why were there only 5 failed pods instead of 6? Or is my understanding about `backoffLimit` in-correct?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In short: You might not be seeing all created pods because period of schedule in the cronjob is too short.

As described in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#pod-backoff-failure-policy):

> Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job
> controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped
> at six minutes. The back-off count is reset if no new failed Pods
> appear before the Job’s next status check.

If new job is scheduled before Job controller has a chance to recreate a pod (having in mind the delay after previous failure), Job controller starts counting from one again.

I reproduced your issue in GKE using following `.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hellocron
spec:
  schedule: "*/3 * * * *" #Runs every 3 minutes
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hellocron
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/cat
            - /etc/os
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 6
  suspend: false
```

This job will fail because file `/etc/os` doesn't exist.

And here is an output of `kubectl describe` for one of the jobs:

```
Name:           hellocron-1551194280
Namespace:      default
Selector:       controller-uid=b81cdfb8-39d9-11e9-9eb7-42010a9c00d0
Labels:         controller-uid=b81cdfb8-39d9-11e9-9eb7-42010a9c00d0
                job-name=hellocron-1551194280
Annotations:    <none>
Controlled By:  CronJob/hellocron
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Tue, 26 Feb 2019 16:18:07 +0100
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 6 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=b81cdfb8-39d9-11e9-9eb7-42010a9c00d0
           job-name=hellocron-1551194280
  Containers:
   hellocron:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      /bin/cat
      /etc/os
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age   From            Message
  ----     ------                ----  ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      26m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-4lf6h
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      26m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-85khk
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      26m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-wrktb
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      26m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-6942s
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      25m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-662zv
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      22m   job-controller  Created pod: hellocron-1551194280-6c6rh
  Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  17m   job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit
```

Note the delay between creation of pods `hellocron-1551194280-662zv` and `hellocron-1551194280-6c6rh`.

Comment: Edited question to include schedule, just a clarification regarding backoffLimit, so backoffLimit` specifies the duration instead of number of pods/restarts that job controller would do. I've created a small [gist](https://gist.github.com/sai-kolluru/93cce5e60652f97f2d7b91b737258c72), is my understanding correct ?

Comment: `backoffLimit` specifies the number of re-tries before job controller gives up.

Comment: @MZW  _I reproduced your issue in GKE_ I see 6 pods are created by your yaml, in my case only 5 pods were created, am I missing something?

Answer (score 25):

Use `spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set to 6 by default.

Comment: what is interval between these 6 retries?

Comment: Is there any value which sets the limit to unlimited?

Comment: You must need to provide some limit

Comment: Anything past about 9, given its an exponential backoff, will become absurdly long.  It could use alternative backoff options, such as "increase by 1 minute each failed attempt".  Exponents are cool initially but become unusable quickly.

Comment: It's an exponential back off delay starting with 10s. So 10s, 20s, 40s, etc. It is capped at 6 mins, so it isn't that crazy to set even a high number of retries.

Comment: If one wants job to never retry, should `backoffLimit: 0` or `backoffLimit:1`? I found, should be `0` but there was a bug with that: github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/67859

Comment: it doesn't seem to be exponential backoff to me, mine is just retrying immediately (Server is at 1.23)