# helm install | Error: failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to do "helm install" using this command:

```
helm install mst local-development/mst
```

However, it runs for some time and gives this error "failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded" as shown below:

```
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-hook-bootstrap" ConfigMap
client.go:297: [debug] configmaps "mst-apps-hook-bootstrap" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-hook-customsql" ConfigMap
client.go:297: [debug] configmaps "mst-apps-hook-customsql" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-hook-dbcreds" Secret
client.go:297: [debug] secrets "mst-apps-hook-dbcreds" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-ltpa-keys" Secret
client.go:297: [debug] secrets "mst-ltpa-keys" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-wlpadm" Secret
client.go:297: [debug] secrets "mst-wlpadm" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-secret-manager" ServiceAccount
client.go:297: [debug] serviceaccounts "mst-apps-secret-manager" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-secret-manager" Role
client.go:297: [debug] roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "mst-apps-secret-manager" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-secret-manager" RoleBinding
client.go:297: [debug] rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "mst-apps-secret-manager" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:268: [debug] Starting delete for "mst-apps-apply-customsql" Job
client.go:297: [debug] jobs.batch "mst-apps-apply-customsql" not found
client.go:122: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:477: [debug] Watching for changes to Job mst-apps-apply-customsql with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:505: [debug] Add/Modify event for mst-apps-apply-customsql: ADDED
client.go:544: [debug] mst-apps-apply-customsql: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:505: [debug] Add/Modify event for mst-apps-apply-customsql: MODIFIED
client.go:544: [debug] mst-apps-apply-customsql: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:505: [debug] Add/Modify event for mst-apps-apply-customsql: MODIFIED
client.go:544: [debug] mst-apps-apply-customsql: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 1, jobs succeeded: 0

client.go:505: [debug] Add/Modify event for mst-apps-apply-customsql: MODIFIED
Error: failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded
helm.go:81: [debug] failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded
```

I tried to modify the command by adding:

```
helm install mst local-development/mst --debug --timeout 10m
```

However, some error emerges.
Any help is appreciated, please.
Thanks,

Comment: Could [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825671/understanding-backofflimit-in-kubernetes-job) help?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your. However, any idea on how to set spec.backoffLimit, please?

Comment: IME if you're hitting this limit it's probably not starting up at all.  But with just the error messages it's a little hard to tell what's going on.  Can you provide an [mcve]?  When the log says `jobs failed: 1` have you looked at what's happening in that job?

Comment: Lot of thanks for your reply, the command I'm using is the same as one I pasted in the question, with the same logs pasted on the question too. My problem is that  I guess tis command should run longer to succeed . One proposition answered above by @JacekLaskowski is to modify  spec.backoffLimit. However, I don't know how to make this. Any idea please?

Comment: As you can see when I run `$ helm install mst local-development/mst` on my cluster it gives me
`Error: failed to download "local-development/mst" (hint: running helm repo update may help)`. Your issue description is still not very helpful. You should've probably started it by telling where you took this helm chart from. Did you run some `helm repo add...` before ? In order to set `spec.backoffLimit` you would need to manually edit components of this helm chart.

Comment: Hello @JimMM. Any updates here?

Comment: @JimMM, please add reproduction steps and answer previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading the helm again, and it worked.